# How to define jQuery in libraries for avoiding conflict with theme with library?

Tags: 8, theming, javascript

For use of most frameworks (Zurb Foundation, Bootstrap, etc) or libraries (Like Owl carousel, Slick, etc) within a theme, jQuery has to be added as a library.

Is it enough to add jQuery only once as dependencies in a `global` library and have it load on every page (imagine that I add this library in Library section of `ThemeName.info.yml`) Or would I have to add it as dependencies each time I define a new library again?

For example, is the below structure correct:

```
global:
  css:
      # The path to the css file.
      assets/css/stylesheets-1.css: {}
      assets/css/stylesheets-2.css: {}
  js:
    assets/js/myglobal.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery

library-A: # Bootstrap Library.
  css:
      assets/css/stylesheets-3.css: {}
      assets/css/stylesheets-4.css: {}
  js:
    assets/js/myglobal.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery

library-B: # Owl carousel Library.
  css:
      assets/css/stylesheets-5.css: {}
      assets/css/stylesheets-6.css {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

Is there any problem If I add jQuery once as library in `js:` category and again as `dependencies:` in one library like `library-C` simultaneously? Something like below? Can it cause the conflict?

```
library-C:
  css:
      assets/css/stylesheets-c-1.css: {}
      assets/css/stylesheets-c-2.css: {}
  js:
    assets/js/myglobal.js: {}
    assets/js/jQuery.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every library needs to have **all** it's dependency listed !
As libraries can be loaded independently.

> drupal will make sure to include every file only once.

So this is correct. yes.

Comment: Thanks for your help and reply, Is there any problem If I add `jQuery` once as library and again as dependency in one library like `library-A` simultaneously?

Comment: the dependency represent an existing library. core/jquery is a library defined in core. so no need to define the jQuery library. you can use a self defined library as dependency in another self defined library.

Comment: Thank you so much for anything again, but I don't think you understand my mean correctly, Please take a look at the bottom of my question again.

Comment: it makes no sense to add 2 jQeury libraries. if you want to update a library, you need to [hook_js_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_js_alter/8.1.x) - with some logic to do it only when your library is required. if you need an older jQuery version, try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21882731/how-to-use-jquery-migrate-plugin, for now, and when drupal updates to jQuery 3 use this [jQuery migrate plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate).

Comment: and please stop extending your question. ask a new one !